# Laravel,Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting

Tags: function, laravel, nested, max

This error is causing me a headache:

> Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting

I have also

> Increase the value of xdebug.max_nesting_level=500 in php.ini file

As well as `increase it in xdebug file`

And also `update my compser`.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: are you restart apache service?

Comment: i restarted my wamp server more than 4 5time ,,but its doesnt work , causing the same error

Comment: I have this problem today and after chang max_nesting_level to 200 my prolem in solve

Comment: in my php.ini file there was not the Line of 'chang max_nesting_level', but i manually place it there and made the value to 500 ,but facing the same error

Comment: Do a composer update and it will be fixed.

Comment: Exactly I do this but I add 200 not 500. change it to 200

Comment: @paranoid now i made it to 200 , but error is still there :(

Comment: @PapaSmurf i also updated my composer, from yestarday i'm trying to fix this error

Comment: run the wamp from admin access?

Comment: nothng happen .. @ujwal dhakal

Answer (score 0):

Change the X-debug item to this:

```
xdebug.remote_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.max_nesting_level=200
```

Comment: should i uninstall wamp server , to get rid of this error ?? and install it again

Comment: witch wamp version you use?? what ih you zend_extension in php.ini

Comment: WampServer Version  is 2.5, and my zend extension is this zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll"